# Is there a way we can perform warping without using cv2.warpAffine()

Tags: python, image-processing

[Flow Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzG8e.jpg)

I'm implementing a algorithm, where as part of iterative refinement process they are performing warping to get the binary mask. I'm able to perform warping, but my results are different from the ones in the paper. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Any kind of help is appreciated. Thank you

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import warnings 

img6 = cv2.imread(r"D:\....\im6.png", 2)
img2 = cv2.imread(r"D:\....\im2.png", 2)
disp_map = cv2.imread(r"D:\....\disp2.png", 2)

h,w = img6.shape
warp = np.zeros((h, w), dtype=np.uint8)
print(h)
print(w)
max_offset = 63.75

for i in range(h):
    for j in range(w):

        value = disp_map[i][j]
        shift = value * max_offset / 255
        if j + int(shift)<w:
            
            warp[i][j + int(shift)] = img6[i][j]

warp = warp.astype(np.uint8)
print(warp.shape)
cv2.imshow("warp", warp)

threshold = 120
bin_mask = np.zeros((h, w), dtype=np.uint8)
for i in range(h):
    for j in range(w):
        if abs(int(img2[i][j]) - int(warp[i][j])) < threshold:
            bin_mask[i][j] = 0
        else:
            bin_mask[i][j] = 255
cv2.imshow("binary mask", bin_mask)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This is my code.
I'm using grayscale images to keep it simple.

[My results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jyd4z.png)

[Results from the paper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TovyP.png)

Paper :https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=9099317

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).